# How do I store a variable that has been created from a user input and use it in a different file in Python?

Tags: python, file, variables, global-variables

I am new to Python and therefore new to the Stack Overflow community. I have embarked on my first mini-project whereby I want to have a random team generator from a group of 6 and assign two random teams. From there I am trying to create two files(one for each team)  where the one user from each time can input each player's score from their team and ultimately I want this to create a live leaderboard in a separate file.
I have successfully created a team generator. This is the essence of it:

```
numberofplayers = int(len(online_players))

number_teams = int(input('How many teams do you want there to be?\n '))

k = int(numberofplayers/number_teams)

if numberofplayers == 6 and number_teams == 2:
    global team_1
    team_1 = random.sample(online_players, k)
    str(team_1)
    for x in team_1:
        online_players.remove(x)
        global team_2
        team_2 = online_players
    print('Team 1')
    
    print(team_1[0] +'(1)')
   
    print(team_1[1] + '(2)')
    
    print('...')
    
   print(team_1[2] +'(3)' +
                      '\n')
    
    print('Team 2')
    print(team_2[0] + '(4)')
   
    print(team_2[1]+ '(5)')
    
    print(team_2[2]+ '(6)')
```

This successfully generates two teams of 3. This file is called Team_Generator.py

In another file called team_1_input.py I use

```
from Team_Generator.py import team_1,team_2
print(team_1)
```

When I run this in the console, it does the whole Team Generator process again and doesn't just use the already assigned teams form Team_Generator.py

Any insight into how I can get it to work so that team_1_input.py recognizes the teams assigned from Team_Generator.py?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this piece of code is also the starting point of your program, you should surround it with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # your code here
```

It will prevent it from being run when the module is imported.

However by importing your main entry point you create a circular dependency: your main file depends on another file that depends on the main file! It can work but it will make you life unnecessarily complicated.

Instead, you should definitely have your other file expose a function that takes the teams as a parameter, and have the main file call it.

```
def do_something_about_teams(team_1, team_2):
    print(team_1)
```

And in your main file:

```
from otherfile import do_something_about_teams

# beginning of main, etc...

do_something_about_teams(team_1, team_2)
```